# Checking what all checkboxes are unchecked?

Tags: jquery

I have something like this:

```
    <form action="">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Lesson Audio / <span class="pricing-box-price">$19.95 USD</span><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Lesson PDFs / <span class="pricing-box-price">$19.95 USD</span><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Review Audio / <span class="pricing-box-price">$19.95 USD</span><br>
      <div class="pricing-levels">
        <p>Which level would you like? (Click all that apply)</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 6<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 7<br>
      </div>
    </form>
```

I want to perform an action when ALL the first three check boxes are unchecked (those above the `.pricing-level` div. How to accomplish that? (Because I want to hide the `.pricing-level` div when they are all unchecked.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
  if($('form > :checked').length == 0){
     //none are checked
  }
```

or more precisely you can do:

```
  if(!$('form > input:checked').length){ //since you don't want to target by name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if($('input[name="vehicle"]:chekced') == 0){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('form > :checked').length === 0){
 // Your action
}
```

This only checks for direct children of the `form` element, thus, skipping all those inside `.pricing-levels`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following :

```
if($('form > :checked').length == 0){
    var x = $('form > :checked').length;
    console.log(x);
    jQuery('.pricing-levels').hide();
}
jQuery('form > input[name=vehicle]').change(function(){
if($('form > :checked').length == 0){
    var x = $('form > :checked').length;
    console.log(x);
    jQuery('.pricing-levels').hide();
}else{
     jQuery('.pricing-levels').show();   
}
});
```

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/ssfQf/